# Youtube app automatically login via webview

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I already login youtube account into my youtube app via OAuth authentication and then I want to make a request to re-login youtube web page with account was login before(open the web view redirect to youtube web page, but no need to login again). Hope you guys to suggest for me the ideas. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please rephrase everything. Use some punctuation, commas and more sentences. It's very hard to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: You may want to check the following documents : [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) and [Obtaining authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) to be familiar on how the authentication flow works. Google APIs support several OAuth 2.0 use cases: server-side flow, client-side flow, installed application flow, device flow. Take note that YouTube Data API does not support service account flow. Hope this helps.